# Eigen Sparse Matrix Multiply with fully custom types

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, eigen

I've got as far as convincing Eigen to do this

```
class A{...};  class B{...}; class Product{...};
auto operator*(const A&,const B&){return Product{..}} 
..operator+..
//"SparseMatrix<A>*SparseVector<B> -> SparseVector<Product>"


SparseMatrix<A> mymat_A; //...
SparseVector<B> myvec_B; //...

SparseVector<Product> result= mymat_A*myvec_B;
```

However what I'm really after is distinct component-Product and output-Accumulator types, e.g.

```
class A{}class B{} class Product{} class Accumulator;
auto operator*(const A&,const B&)->Product{..}
auto operator+=(Accumulator& lhs,const Product& p){lhs+=p;return lhs;}

SparseVector<Accumulator> result = mymat_A*myvec_B
```

Is this possible? I've needed to setup eigen's type-traits for the A,B,Prod here to get this far, and setup these
template<>
struct Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<A,B,Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<A, B> >{
typedef Product ReturnType;
};

I had thought I could hint the existence of a seperate product using "..sum..<Product,Product> -> Accumulator, supplying overloads for Prod+Prod->Acc, but this didn't work.

use cases= mixed precision with small products but many such that you need a larger accumulator, and doing non-arithmetic things (information flowing across graphs) that just happens to fit the storage and traversal pattern optimizations needed for sparse matrix mul.

If this isn't possible, perhaps someone can recommend an alternate sparse-matrix library which can do this.

If I succumb to NIH and just roll my own, my design for this would have been as follows - just use decltype to infer the existence of seperate sum/product types from operator overloads (supplying a custom product type with summation overload yielding the desired accumulator). but it would use Acc+=Prod internally (after declaring decltype(Prod+Prod) accumulators initialized to '0'.)

```
template<typename A,typename B>
SparseVector<decltype(A()*B()+A()*B())>  operator*(const SparseMatrix<A>& ,const SparseVector<B>&){...}

// supply appropriate operator+, +=...
```

Current code (single source file that compiles with clang if Eigen is in the path)

```
#pragma once
#include <Eigen/Sparse>

// setup for MatElem*VecElem->Prod
// goal is to add Prod+Prod->Acc,  Acc+=Prod,  Acc(Prod) Acc=0
class MatElem {public:MatElem(){} MatElem(int x){}};
class VecElem {public:VecElem(){} VecElem(int x){}};
class Prod {public:Prod(){} Prod(int x){}};
class Acc {public:Acc(){} Acc(const Prod&){printf("Acc(Prod)");} Acc(Prod&){printf("Acc(Prod)");} Acc(int x){}};
auto operator*(const MatElem& a,const VecElem& b){printf("MatElem*VecElem\n");return Prod{};}
auto operator+(const Prod& a,const Prod& b){printf("Prod+Prod\n");return Prod{};}
auto operator+=(Prod& a,const Prod& b){printf("Prod+=Prod\n");return a;}
auto operator+=(Acc& a,const Prod& b){printf("Acc+=Prod\n");return a;}
template<>
class Eigen::NumTraits<MatElem> {
public:
    typedef MatElem Real;
    typedef MatElem NonInteger; 
    typedef MatElem Literal;
    typedef MatElem Nested;
    enum {
        IsInteger=0,
        IsSigned=1,
        RequireInitialization=1,
        IsComplex=0,
        ReadCost=1,
        AddCost=1,
        MulCost=1
        
    };
    auto static epsilon(){return MatElem();}
    auto static dummy_precision(){return MatElem();}
    auto static highest(){return MatElem();}
    auto static lowest(){return MatElem();}
    auto static digist10(){return 5;}
};

template<>
class Eigen::NumTraits<VecElem> {
public:
    typedef VecElem Real;
    typedef VecElem NonInteger; 
    typedef VecElem Literal;
    typedef VecElem Nested;
    enum {
        IsInteger=0,
        IsSigned=1,
        RequireInitialization=1,
        IsComplex=0,
        ReadCost=1,
        AddCost=1,
        MulCost=1
        
    };
    auto static epsilon(){return VecElem{};}
    auto static dummy_precision(){return VecElem{};}
    auto static highest(){return VecElem{};}
    auto static lowest(){return VecElem{};}
    auto static digist10(){return 5;}
};
template<>
class Eigen::NumTraits<Prod> {
public:
    typedef Prod Real;
    typedef Prod NonInteger;    
    typedef Prod Literal;
    typedef Prod Nested;
    enum {
        IsInteger=0,
        IsSigned=1,
        RequireInitialization=1,
        IsComplex=0,
        ReadCost=1,
        AddCost=1,
        MulCost=1
        
    };
    auto static epsilon(){return Prod{};}
    auto static dummy_precision(){return Prod{};}
    auto static highest(){return Prod{};}
    auto static lowest(){return Prod{};}
    auto static digist10(){return 5;}
};

template<>
class Eigen::NumTraits<Acc> {
public:
    typedef Acc Real;
    typedef Acc NonInteger; 
    typedef Acc Literal;
    typedef Acc Nested;
    enum {
        IsInteger=0,
        IsSigned=1,
        RequireInitialization=1,
        IsComplex=0,
        ReadCost=1,
        AddCost=1,
        MulCost=1
        
    };
    auto static epsilon(){return Acc{};}
    auto static dummy_precision(){return Acc{};}
    auto static highest(){return Acc{};}
    auto static lowest(){return Acc{};}
    auto static digist10(){return 5;}
};

template<>
struct Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<MatElem,VecElem,Eigen::internal::scalar_product_op<MatElem, VecElem> >{
    typedef Prod ReturnType;
};

template<>
struct Eigen::ScalarBinaryOpTraits<Prod,Prod,Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<Prod, Prod> >{
    typedef Prod ReturnType;
};


void eigen_experiment() {
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<MatElem> mymat(3,3);
    mymat.insert(0,0)=MatElem{};
    mymat.insert(0,1)=MatElem{};
    mymat.insert(1,0)=MatElem{};
    mymat.insert(1,1)=MatElem{};
    Eigen::SparseVector<VecElem> myvec(3);
    myvec.insert(0)=VecElem{};
    myvec.insert(1)=VecElem{};
    // Can't seem to do this with "Acc", even if supplying appropriate OpTraits etc above.
    Eigen::SparseVector<Prod> tmp=mymat*myvec;
    
    for (int k=0; k<mymat.outerSize(); ++k){
        for (decltype(mymat)::InnerIterator v(mymat,k); v;++v){
            printf("%d %d\n",v.row(),v.col());
        }
    }

    for (decltype(tmp)::InnerIterator v(tmp); v;++v){
        printf("%d\n",v.index());
    }
}

int main(int argc,const char**){
    eigen_experiment();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you unify `Product` and `Accumulator` (or at least make the first implicitly be convertible to the second). Your result needs to be able to store elements which are just a single `A*B` product and not the sum of multiple products.

Comment: Also please post a [mre] of what you got so far (i.e., something that would compile except for the final sparse product).

Comment: It's fine to supply an implicit conversion eg  a constructor or assignment operator Accumulator(Product).  Unifying these types however restricts a use case I have in mind - where the accumulator type is nontrivial . I can paste my "min reproducable example", 1min..

Comment: ok the code I had so far is pasted in the original comment . It just sets up dummy matrix and the operators just print to verify they're being called.

Comment: If you set the return types of both binary traits to `Acc`, do you get the behavior you want? https://godbolt.org/z/931Kxoa36

Comment: Getting a direct `Acc(Prod+Prod)` instead of `Acc(Prod)+=Prod` will be very complicated, even if you hand-code this. You would need to keep track or know ahead of time for each element of the result if it will be composed of a single `Prod` or the sum of at least two. (In theory, this would be easier with dense products, but also not with Eigen).

Comment: Acc(Prod)+=Prod would be fine, I can definitely do this without a Prod+Prod->Acc.  I'll try changing return types of the binary_op traits again, but its vital (for the fully general case) that individual products are Prod (guaranteed trivial type), then they're summed into a 'Acc' (potentially non trivial type). "scalar_product_op<MatElem, VecElem>::ReturnType" must be Prod, not Acc.

Comment: @chtz, thanks actually that godbolt example - "just setting both ReturnTypes" to Acc looks right. I guess its still using the operator to generate the products, so that remains 'Prod' .the prints there seem to do what I want. Thanks a lot, it's encouraging

Answer (score 0):

thanks @chtz , just setting both the operator traits to "Accumulator" (the desired output) whilst the actual operator overloads return the temporary "Product" type, it just works. I didn't think to try it but it seems it just uses the trait to allocate the outputs, and of course it doesn't affect the actual operator. The debug prints appear to confirm its doing what I wanted.